# Codename one's VKB not showing in android build

Tags: codenameone

I have installed an android build of codename one on motorola atrix.

Now I have a textfield. WHen I click on the textfield, android's keyboard shows up.

I don't want that. I want to show [Codename One's](http://www.codenameone.com) key board(white and transparent). How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an API called `Display.setDefaultVirtualKeyboard()` but it probably won't work for Android since we use native input on Android always by default. The keyboard is the smaller issue, the copy/paste and other features available on these OS's are the main reason we chose the native keyboard.

You can file a bug on this and we can evaluate the complexity of adding something like this, but it will probably be a bit of a pain to fix.

Comment: Oh ok. Well I have added a textfield,associated an hint with it & added a data change listener to it. Now i have a list, whose contents refresh whenever the data in textfield changes. The implementation is the same as in the example given by u for contacts list and a fish keeps swimming in the background.

Now in android, with Android's keyboard, the HINT of the textfield, remains visible when the data is being typed (bad UI feel) in the textfield. Also, the contents of the list don't refresh immediately on the fly(poor user experience). Hence i thot C1's keyboard will rectify this

Comment: based on your above comment, i tried out the code given in the answer posted by me..and now codename one's keyboard shows up

Comment: ok, so android's keyboard is more easier to use. 

In C1's keyboard...there is a drawback. When the cursor has some text IN FRONT of it, the user cannot delete it. The user can only delete text that is behind the cursor. This drawback, can be overcome by clicking on T9(show's the android keyboard) , then manipulating the text.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so with Shai's comment given above: this is how i got android to show codename one's keyboard.

```
Textfield field = new TextField();

        VirtualKeyboard vkb = new VirtualKeyboard();
        VirtualKeyboard.bindVirtualKeyboard(field, vkb);//binding the vkb to a particular textfield
        Display.getInstance().setDefaultVirtualKeyboard(vkb);
```

Now, the datachange listener for textfield works smooth. Also the hint of the textfield clears out when textfield receives focus.